# how to filter the nsdictionary with multiple keys in swift?

Tags: swift

```
{
    address = "street1";
    country = India;
    state = uttarpradesh;
}
{
    address = "street2";
    country = US;
    state = New York;
}
```

this is my dictionary

I am using search bar for filter

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

     // Put your key in predicate that is "Name"


    let filteredArray = MyDict.filter { ($0["address"] as! String).range(of: searchText!,  ($0["country"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, ($0["state"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }

    print ("array = \(filteredArray)")

    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I have never seen a Swift dictionary like that before.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a Swift Dictionary? Also, avoid naming your var starting with an uppercase. And you can should do "or": `if let inFactAnArray = MyDict as? [[String: String]] { let filteredArray = inFactAnArray.filter{ $0["address"].range(of...) || $0["country"].range(of:)... || ... } }` And `MyDict` is in fact an Array of Dictionaries. Bad naming is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
let filteredArray = MyDict.filter { ($0["address"] as! String).range(of: searchText!,  ($0["country"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, ($0["state"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```

Use `&&` to require that two bool expressions be true or `||` to make an expression that is true if either is true.

So, to check if the address OR (`||`) the county has the text, use

```
let filteredArray = MyDict.filter { 
   ($0["address"] as! String).range(of: searchText!) != nil ||  
   ($0["country"] as! String).range(of: searchText!) != nil 
}
```

You can add more checks with more `||` and sub-expressions

From the dictionary you showed, however, it's not clear to me that Country is a String.  You would need to convert whatever it is to the country name as a String.

Comment: Value of tuple type '(key: Any, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'  it showing error

Answer (score 0):

Presuming in your example `MyDict` is an array of `NSDictionary`:

```
let filteredArray = MyDict.filter {
    for key in $0.allKeys {
        if let string = $0[key] as? String,
            string.contains(searchText) {
            return true 
        }
    }
    return false
}
searchActive = filteredArray.count > 0
```

Additionally you might find it very useful to familiarise yourself with the basics of [Swift guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/)